# ReactJS: componentDidMount, componentWillUnmount

Tags: reactjs

Объясните, пожалуйста, дилетанту две вещи:

```
componentDidMount
componentWillUnmount
```

Я правильно понимаю, первое выполняется после первого успешного рендера, а второе перед удалением элемента из виртуального DOM?

Прокомментируйте, если не затруднит, развернуто.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Метод `componentDidMount` вызывается сразу после первой отрисовки компонента. В этом методе, как правило, делают асинхронные запросы, инициализации таймеров и прочее. Также с этого момента доступны ссылки через свойство `refs`.

Метод `componentWillUnmount` выполняется непосредственно перед отсоединением компонента от дерева DOM. Здесь принято производить разного рода чистку: удаление каких-либо элементов, остановка таймеров, прерывание запросов к серверу, если они еще не были завершены.

Comment: Благодарю. Расскажите про ссылки через свойство refs?

Comment: Вот нашел хороший гид по жизненному циклу компонентов React для начинающих (таких, как я=): https://github.com/krambertech/react-essential-course/tree/master/02-deep-in-components

Comment: @pravosleva, ответы на все вопросы которые вы тут задаете по реаткту описаны в родной документации подробно. https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html 
Понимаю что английский знают не все, но все таки попробовать посмотреть родные доки быстрее, чем ждать когда кто-нибудь их перескажет

Comment: @Утка, да вы, прям, зрите в корень. Честно говоря, я сам ценю оригинальную документацию больше любого перевода (хотя бы потому, что она всегда будет более полная), но есть в ней некоторые моменты, требующие владения английским (возможно, на уровне выше среднего), к примеру, устойчивые выражения, которые (внимание, это ключевой замысловатый посыл!) я бы хотел послушать, как поняли другие чуваки, те, что владеют русским языком так же хорошо как и материалом, который они усвоили. Я думаю, нет ничего необычного в моих ожиданиях от русскоязычного ресурса.